# Does the MS2 RNA binding protein have any translational repression effects?

Tags: molecular-biology, translation

Reposted from Quora: http://www.quora.com/Does-the-MS2-RNA-binding-protein-have-any-translational-repression-effects

I'm thinking of the MS2 protein binding to its RNA hairpin target. Would the interaction of the MS2 protein to the hairpin placed upstream of a ORF cause any translational repression?

Comment: Why don't you place the MS2L downstream of the ORF? What exactly is the experiment you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the mTAG visualization technique for mRNAs [(1)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19680241). You are probably familiar with it, but the OFR of interest is tagged with MS2L sequence downstream of it and upstream of the 3'UTR. There is also a modified version, in which you can visualize both the mRNA of interest, and the protein that is translated, see the figure below [(2)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3222136/). Haim and colleagues found that yeast expressing mCherry and MS2L tagged ATP2 grew on glycerol-containing media, which would require efficient translation of ATP2.

[image]

So I would assume that there is no translational repression if you tag the mRNA downstream of the ORF. Unless you have a very good reason to tag the ORF of interest with MS2 upstream of the start codon, I wouldn't do it, because these stem-loop structures would most probably stall translation, as mRNA secondary structure has been implicated in translation initiation efficiency.

Comment: The idea would actually be to repress translation via the mecahnism that you suggest. Hence, the rationale of putting the MS2 hairpin upstream of the ORF.

Comment: Oh I see now... Interesting idea. Worth exploring. Why don't you use Cas9?

Comment: Probably because I asked this question back in 2012 and was more of a curiosity question rather than an actual experimental question. More specifically, I'm concerned more about generating a tuneable analog type of repression system where you can generate a range of repress rather than perform a complete knockdown using CRISPR.